# How RecursiveTask works for calculating Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: recursion, java-8, fork-join

I am looking at the classical example for RecursiveTask calculating Fibonacci numbers. I added some output:  see http://jboston.net/2017/FibonacciOutp.txt, the code is below

Still cannot understand how this is working, why first we see all numbers decreasing from 12 and then  repeating many times

number=2 fcal1.join()=1 fcal2.compute()=0

number=3 fcal1.join()=1 fcal2.compute()=1

The code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

public class RecursiveTaskDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FibonacciCal fibonacciCal = new FibonacciCal(12);
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    int i = pool.invoke(fibonacciCal);
    System.out.println(i);
}
}

class FibonacciCal extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
final int num;

FibonacciCal(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

@Override
protected Integer compute() {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return num;
    }
    System.out.println("number=" + num);
    FibonacciCal fcal1 = new FibonacciCal(num - 1);
    fcal1.fork();
    FibonacciCal fcal2 = new FibonacciCal(num - 2);
    int fcal1Join = fcal1.join();
    int fcal2Compute = fcal2.compute();
    System.out.println("number=" + num + " fcal1.join()=" + fcal1Join + " fcal2.compute()=" + fcal2Compute);
    return fcal2Compute + fcal1Join;
}

}
```

Comment: It creates bunch of processes to calculate Fibonacci series, but actually it does nothing (no code for calculation)

Comment: It's worth noting that your example doesn't solve the problem of Fibonacci number calculation efficiently since you don't perform computation on _fcal2_ task object until computation of _fcal1_ task completes. To solve that _bug_, _fcal1.join()_ should be called after _fcal2.compute()_.

Comment: At example, if we add 1 second delay at the beginning of _compute_ method body, calculation for your sample would take 468 seconds instead of ~70.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `FibonacciCal::compute` is called, it forks off one thread to calculate `fib(n - 1)` and computes `fib(n - 2)` in the starting thread. The branching looks a bit like this (`fib(n)` represents a thread running `FibonacciCal(n).compute()`):

```
STARTING WITH pool.invoke(new FibonacciCal(5)):
fib(5)
A BIT LATER:
fib(5) === fib(3) // The fibcal2.compute() call, printing num = 3
       \== fib(4) // The fibcal1.fork() call, printing num = 4
LATER:
fib(5) === fib(3) === fib(1) // These fib(0/1)s are base cases and will start folding the tree back up
       |          \== fib(2) === fib(0) // Will return 1 and not fork
       |                     \== fib(1) // Will return 1 and not fork
       \== fib(4) === fib(2) === fib(0)
                  |          \== fib(1)
                  \== fib(3) === fib(1)
                             \== fib(2) === fib(0)
                                        \== fib(1)
METHODS START RETURNING:
fib(5) === fib(3) === 1
       |          \== fib(2) === 1
       |                     \== 1
       \== fib(4) === fib(2) === 1
                  |          \== 1
                  \== fib(3) === 1
                             \== fib(2) === 1
                                        \== 1
ADDITIONS START HAPPENING:
fib(5) === fib(3) === 1
       |          \== (1 + 1) = 2 // When a thread joins its child, it prints out its number again.
       |                          // Since the tree is now folding instead of unfolding, the printlns appear, approximately, the opposite order
       \== fib(4) === (1 + 1) = 2
                  \== fib(3) === 1
                             \== (1 + 1) = 2
LATER:
fib(5) === (1 + 2) = 3 === 1
       |               \== 2
       \== fib(4) === 2
                  \== (1 + 2) = 3 === 1
                                  \== 2
END:
8 === 3 === 1
  |     \== 2
  \== 5 === 2
        \== 3 === 1
              \== 2
```

The reason you get a lot of repeating numbers is because there isn't any memoization. In this example with `fib(5)` you see that you get 8 base terms of `fib(0)` or `fib(1)`, 3 terms of `fib(2)`, 2 of `fib(3)`, and one `fib(4)`. As the lower order terms start joining their children you get lots of printlns with small `num`s, until the end comes and they start counting back up.